# video in a Splashscreen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How to put a video in a splash screen in Windows Phone 8 Application development. I am using visual Studio 2012. I am new in Windows development. If possible give me the coding. Thanx in advance

Comment: I would try to use MediaElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Comment: Follow the link here http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/all-about-splash-screens-in-wp7-ndash-creating-animated-splash-screen

Comment: The answer is mentioned but that is not generally advised dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can keep an image in your project by name SplashScreenImage.jpg. It will directly show this particular image on starting and you can also extend the time to show that image.